# List of website links of specific domain

Tags: search, dns, web

I'm looking for Internet site (or search engine), what have listed all sites of chosen domain (specifically .ch ). I performed a research, but I didn't find nothing more useful than "100 best websites in net". Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to search google by domain using the site: prefix

Example:

```
site:.ch best web sites on net
```

It is not possible to get a list of all sites because of a number of reasons. There can be an infinite number of sub-domains for any domain. Most countries TLD registries ccTLD don't publish their domain lists. Not every domain needs to be configured to an IP running a web server. Web sites can also be hidden on ports other than the default port 80. There is also the Tor network and possibly other similar services where sites can be hidden behind proxies. You can of course buy domain lists from various web sites but these lists will be incomplete.